# How do I build my Titanium app over SSH? I get a CodeSign error

Tags: ssh, titanium

When I connect to my MacBook over SSH and run this code:

```
titanium build \
    --force \
    --platform ios \
    --device-family universal \
    --target dist-adhoc \
    --distribution-name "[NAME]" \
    --pp-uuid "[UUID]" \
    --output-dir "./"
```

I get the following error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CodeSign build/Release-iphoneos/App.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over SSH, first run this command and enter the password:

```
security unlock-keychain
```